# Incremental backup in Solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I need to take backup of Apache-Solr's saved data. I enabled replication in solrconfig.xml and doing backup through http-api. Is there anyway to take incremental backup? That is I have 5 GB of data. First time the backup has been taken. When the data size increased to 5.5 GB, the additional data of 0.5 GB alone needs to be taken as backup in the second time. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can a snapshot of Complete index (Not Incremental) through [HTTP Api](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#HTTP_API).
You can configure the number of back ups to maintain as well and on what condition to backup the index.